# File Upload Deny Animated GIFs (using PHP/Zend Framework)

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, file-upload

i am thinking i may want users to be able to upload static GIFs but not animated ones. say for avatar's as they may look ... unprofessional and distracting. is there a way in PHP or Zend Framework that i can validate a file upload that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library to save your images. With gif type of files is saves only first frame from gif file if it animated. See [imagegif](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) function for more info how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Form the [PHP: imagecreatefromgif - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php):

```
I wrote two alternate versions of ZeBadger's is_ani() function, for determining if a gif file is animated

Original:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php#59787

The first alternative version is just as memory intensive as the original, and more CPU intensive, but far simpler:

<?php
function is_ani($filename) {
    return (bool)preg_match('#(\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00\x2C.*){2,}#s', file_get_contents($filename));
}
?>

The second alternative is about as CPU intensive as the original function, but uses less memory (and may also result in less disk activity)

<?php
function is_ani($filename) {
    if(!($fh = @fopen($filename, 'rb')))
        return false;
    $count = 0;
    //an animated gif contains multiple "frames", with each frame having a
    //header made up of:
    // * a static 4-byte sequence (\x00\x21\xF9\x04)
    // * 4 variable bytes
    // * a static 2-byte sequence (\x00\x2C)

    // We read through the file til we reach the end of the file, or we've found
    // at least 2 frame headers
    while(!feof($fh) && $count < 2)
        $chunk = fread($fh, 1024 * 100); //read 100kb at a time
        $count += preg_match_all('#\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00\x2C#s', $chunk, $matches);

    fclose($fh);
    return $count > 1;
}
?>
```